# finding a base and dimension of a 3 x 3 matrix that represents all skew-symmetric matrices above the complex field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm suppose to find that matrix, and I was only given the final answer of the dimension which is 3.

But everything I tried so far is leading me to one of the rows being zeroed and therefore the dimension isn't 3.

I know the form of skew-symmetric matrices well, but so far I only dealt with it above the rational numbers, maybe I am missing something.

The matrix have to represent all 3x3 skew symmetric matrices above COMPLEX field.

Comment: @DietrichBurde but isnt that touching only the skew-symmetric matrices of rational numbers?

Comment: @Shames That's good for matrices over *any* field.